# How to animate a pencil bent in a circle? (Animated logo)

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I am new to Blender. Can anyone help me to create this animation?

[image: bent pencil animation]

I am trying to create this animation.
Original link: https://dribbble.com/shots/11016610-C-Logo

Comment: A question that only relies on a link is very bad. If the link goes down nobody knows what this question was about. Also, the title is not very descriptive. What is "this animation"? (Yes, you can see it now, but people who have a similar question often use a search engine or the built-in search to find answers. Try to search for "this animation" ;-)

Comment: Thank you for redeeming this question @Blunder ;)

Comment: I will try do that next time. First time using blender stack also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

The characteristics of this animation are:

- The arc varies in length
- The whole object is rotated around the center
- The object is rotated along the curve
- The only thing that changes/stretches is the middle part of the pencil

My solution is based on an interplay of animated *Group Inputs* (keyframed) and partially flexible designed elements. All however procedurally created with Geometry Nodes.

The most important part of this technique is based on rotating and trimming a curve (non cyclic circle, or arc).

The endpoints (the pencil tip as well as the eraser) do not change their shape, but only the middle part, and therefore can be replaced by any object.

Therefore, I essentially created three objects, with only the middle part creating a changing mesh (depending on the length of the arc).

So how you ultimately implement the eraser or the pencil tip is more of an artistic question, but I went the following way, as it seemed the most flexible:

### Setting the Inputs

First I set the controllable values as *Group Inputs*:

- The rotation of the whole object (keyframed).
- The trim factor of the arc (keyframed)
- The rotation of the object or the *Curve Tilt* (keyframed)
- The number of sides of the pencil
- The resolution for pencil tip and the eraser

### Middle Part

1. As a base I use `Curve Circle` to create a circle with a resolution of $120$ points. This seemed high enough to me, but can be increased or lowered as desired.
2. To get a controllable arc, I apply the node `Set Spline Cyclic` and deactivate the option *Cyclic*. This gives me an open arc that I can control with the node `Trim Curve` and the previously created *Group Input*.
3. So that I can also control the rotation of the object, I use the *Tilt* property of the curve. However, so that the value defined via *Group Inputs* also always generates a rotation from one end to the other end of the arc, I use the node `Map Range` and feed it additionally with the value *Factor*, which the node `Spline Parameter` gives me.

   This creates a consistent rotation from the beginning to the end, but always controlled by the *Group Input*.
4. I then get the mesh for the middle part by creating another circle along this thus generated curve with the node `Curve to Mesh`.

### The Pencil Tip

1. I create the pencil tip using the node `Mesh Boolean` because I wanted to derive it from the shape of the middle part.

   For this I first create a cylinder, which has the same number of sides as the middle part, and a cone.

   So that I can also specify the material differently after the boolean operation, I additionally capture a boolean value with the node `Capture Attribute`.
2. The trick with the tip here is that I previously created a Cone with two side segments. With a little logic (See "Select Tip") I select a part of the faces so that I can scale the tip separately and assign it its own material.

   Note: Decisive here are also the places where I define the materials with the node `Set Material`.

### The Eraser

This end is not really dependent on the rest of the part, and can actually be shaped any way you want.

I'm basically just forming an object out of two cylinders here that is similar to the one in your example.

I deliberately made it this way here to show other ways objects can be deformed.

But you can also use more complex shapes, like a hemisphere or similar.

### Joining Elements

The only important thing is that the object for the pencil tip fits seamlessly to the middle part, and that these, as well as the eraser, are positioned correctly. The node `Transform` sets the two objects in such a way that they extend both ends of the arc.

So that I can now join the parts correctly, I first combine the pencil tip and the eraser into one group, in which each of the two objects is contained as an instance. I achieve this by using the node `Geometry to Instances`.

This way I am able to instantiate the two elements on the previously created arc with the node `Instance on Points` using their index.

Converting the arc to points with the node `Curve to Points` has two reasons: On the one hand I can get exactly two points (start point and end point of the curve), and on the other hand I get the rotation of these points.

Since the input geometry has only two points, and the instance group consists of only two instances, one object is instantiated at one end, and the other object at the other end.

*Note: Since this example is about a pencil with an unusual number of sides, and I wanted to reproduce the picture as exactly as possible, I came here to $9$ sides and a slight rotation, which I transfer before additionally as rotation to the three elements.*

And now I have three elements that are separated from each other, but fit together seamlessly.

Since no closed mesh was necessary, I did not merged any points, but left the elements as they are and simply joined them with the Node `Join Geometry`.

To avoid irregularities in the shading due to the existing normals, I switched off the smoothing of the mesh with the node `Set Smooth`. It is not really necessary in this example and can be controlled relatively well by the resolution of the basic shapes.

At the very end, I apply the rotation controlled by *Group Input* to the entire object.

### Animation

Now that all the relevant parts are sufficiently flexible with this technique, the animation is just a matter of correctly set keyframes.

As you can see in the example, here over a range of $120$ frames just the values **Rotation**, **Trim Factor** and **Tilt** are animated.

With a little playing around, you then get pretty much what you show in your example.

### The Node Tree

In any case, you have a lot of material in this example that is great for learning a little more about Geometry Nodes:

[image]

*PS: I have hidden some of the irrelevant sockets to save some space. You can show them again with the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.*

[image]

Comment: I really would like the explanation on this.   Thank you very much .

Comment: @AkhilRP OK, it's not easy because this is a very individual example, but I'll give it a try....

Comment: You are GN killer born as a pure patience :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a curve modifier like this one to curve the pencil around the circle (if you made the pencil from a cylinder, you should change deform axis to Z):

[image]

Now then you move the pencil in deform axis (in my case is Z) it moves along the circle:

[image]

To extend the length, add 2 shape keys in the pencil:

[image]

And in edit mode, move the top part. I have a lot of loopcuts in the model to make the curve smooth:

[image]

So that I selected top part and move it with linear proportional editing enabled:

[image]

[image]

Don't forget to disable proportional editing.

Now in object mode, if you change shape key influence it will extend:

[image]

All that's left is to animate shape key influence and Z position.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: i tried animating with shape key and z position but I couldn't do the animations as in the animation above @Crantisz.