# I am trying to model a pencil. Can you help me in modeling this pencil?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model this pencil

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reconstructing the geometry from from the answer to your previous question ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265462/86891

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a 8 vertex circle, subdivide twice:

[image]

Extrude up, move up the inner vertices:

[image]

Extrude up again, then keep the top edge selected and right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Bevel these edges:

[image]

Extrude and scale down the top to create the tip, create another circle at the base of the slope to make it rounder:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As for creating the effect where towards the end and on the cone section there are "half circles" at the end of the "hexagonal cylinder" part, what you could do is have a high definition circle cylinder, with at least 32 vertices, but the more the better, and then use cubes with the boolean modifier to "Scrape" off the wood into the final shape, like this

[image]