# I am trying to bend a pencil shape along a curve path. How can I bend the pencil like in the pic?

Tags: modeling, animation, curve-modifier

[image: Bend like this]

[image: My version of bend]

I need to bend the pencil as in the first image which is without affecting the top and bottom. But in mine there is bend in the tip part and at eraser part which i don't need.

Thanks to the community I modeled the pencil.

Comment: Just use the answer to your question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265460/how-to-animate-a-pencil-bent-in-a-circle-animated-logo) but don't animate it?

Comment: I'm a little confused: you're showing a rendering here that was created with the file I gave in response to one of your questions. In this file I do exactly what you ask here. And I deliberately built this file so that there would be no bending of the ends. So I don't quite understand this...

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. This is a duplicate of your previous post that already has answers, and seems to be the third question covering this topic. Why is this being asked again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose it is not possible without a little hack. You have to detach top and bottom part of the object so that they will not be affected by modifier. Do it like so:

1. Disable curve modifier.
2. Select top part and detach it from the shape using <kbd>P</kbd> ⇾ *Separate selection*.
3. Same from bottom part.

Now, to make separated parts of the mesh follow the main part, do a vertex parent:

4. Select top part and main with shift. Go in edit mode and select 3 vertices from main part. You should see the highlighted edges on the main part:

[image]

5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> ⇾ *Make vertex parent*.
6. Same for the other part.
7. If you made everything correct, you will see that the top and the bottom part follow the main body, then you turn on the curve modifier:

[image]

You can also add a twist to it

[image]

Comment: i have done like this and sometimes its not following the main part. And then when i got the right there was some problem like it was not attaching to main part perfectly. And i don't know how i got that right at first.

Comment: I suppose you can disable modifiers and reparent, if you have some troubles

Comment: should i apply all the transforms

Comment: I'm not sure, give it a try

Comment: THANKS @Crantisz, I completed it.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the simple deform modifier for that and play around with the limits:

[image]